# Safest way/practice to call c++ dll which can crash or stuck

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, dllimport

Let's assume that I have some dll's. One can freeze indefinitely or run some UI methods of its own for too long. The other can crash with either simple or Corrupted State Exceptions.

Is there some already developed general universal practice/method/wrapper to load and run imported methods of both dll types, handle and log all unsafe exceptions if they occur and be able to close the dll process if it is not responding for too long while keeping my own caller c# app saefly away from all those issues?

Comment: What do you mean by both dll typed? Managed and unmanaged?

Comment: You can make another application that calls these methods and pass the results over RPC or similar tech.

Comment: @Ralf, by "both" I mean both I've mentioned - which either crashes or hangs for long time so I need to terminate them. I'm asking about unmanaged or just about more or less universal way to safely run any potentially troublesome dll.

Comment: Put the crappy code in a different process